# Request is too large

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload a file around 7 GB to google cloud storage. I used the HttpRequest class to upload. I choosed "resumable" upload. I also set the readtimeout to be 20000000.

If I upload smaller file, if works fine. For bigger file, such as 6GB. It returns:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
Request is too large.
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1050)
```

Is there any one who successfully uploaded a larger file around 10GB to Google Cloud Storage?
How did you make it?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have enabled 'resumable upload', HttpRequest.execute() is attempting to upload the full file during a single request.

You have to create separate HttpRequests, each sending a 256KB chunk.

[Resumable Upload Documentation](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#resumable)

> Chunk size restriction: All chunks must be a multiple of 256 KB (256 x 1024 bytes) in size, except for the final chunk that completes the upload. If you use chunking, it is important to keep the chunk size as large as possible to keep the upload efficient.